# Extracting a specific cell with SimpleXLSX to PHP

Tags: php, xlsx

**Hi**
This should be pretty simple but I can't figure it out. Can anyone tell me how I can extract one specific cell (like B4 in the spreedsheet)?

I can do something like this (from the included examples) to get all the cells, but I only want this exact one!

```
        echo '<tr>';
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_cols; $i ++ ) {
            echo '<td>' . ( ! empty( $r[ $i ] ) ? $r[ $i ] : '&nbsp;' ) . '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) or any other package like this.
You will get much functionality for working with excel.

```php
$spreadSheet = new Spreadsheet();
$cellValue = $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B4')->getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $xlsx->getCell(0, 'C1');
```